# Slide animation only with one div

Tags: jquery, css, animation, this, mouseover

I have a little problem, I want to create a slide animation. You can see my code : 
[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/mz6Xp/2/).

But as you can see, when we "mouseover" on just one div all the divs are animated ! 
I want to : that when we "mouseover" on one div, just THIS div be animate, and no the others.

```
$(".button span").mouseover( function() {
$(this).stop().animate({ height:"+5%"}, 500);}); }); $(function() {

$(".button").mouseout( function(){
$(".button span").stop().animate({ height:"150px"}, 500);});

$(".button").mouseover( function(){
$(".button span").stop().animate({ height:"+5%"}, 500);});
```

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: your code is messed up... try fixing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `this` as the context for selecting the span:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKcSU/

```
$(function () {
    $(".button").mouseout(function () {
        $('span', this).stop().animate({
            height: "150px"
        }, 500);
    });

    $(".button").mouseover(function () {
        $('span', this).stop().animate({
            height: "+5%"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Alternatives would be `$(this).find('span')` or `$(this).children('span');`

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/mz6Xp/8/), using `$(this)`!

```
$(".button span").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: "+5%"
    }, 500);
});
$(".button span").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: "150px"
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKcSU/1/)

use this as the context for selecting the span

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".button").hover(function () {
        $('span', this).stop().animate({
            height: "+5%"
        }, 500);
    }, function () {

        $('span', this).stop().animate({
            height: "150px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```